# 2 Names in one <input>

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I was wondering if I could declare **two** different **names** in one input tag e.g. `<input type='text' name='food' name='user_search_input'>`.
In my PHP-file I would use the input in two different "if clauses", one is for a search and the other one would insert the users input into a database. Therefore I need two names to "trigger" these two if clauses.

Comment: Not sure that it will work, but you definitely can solve it on different way. :)

Comment: Please be more specific, post some code :)

Comment: This question might help with your answer: [1 Input Multiple Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353076/one-input-field-multiple-names)

Comment: Think a bit farther ahead: How would you get PHP to store two values in the same variable?

Comment: I don't understand why you would do this? Why can't you just use one variable with the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think it will work but you can do this in other way,like:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='food' name='user_search_input'>
```

PHP:

```
$var1=$_POST['food'];
```

and so:
in one if

```
if($var1){
do the search 
}
```

in other if

```
if($var1){
insert into a database
}
```